# T-SQL COALESCE GROUPING SETS into single column without NULL duplicates

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, select, hierarchical-data, coalesce

A thesaurus database where terms and categories are linked to each other and running SQL Server 2008.
Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4301074/t-sql-select-combine-multiple-rows-into-one-column) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/956065/sql-group-rows-with-same-value-and-put-that-value-into-header) answers. Here is a sample:

```
CREATE TABLE #term (termid VARCHAR(8), en VARCHAR(32), enscope VARCHAR(32))
CREATE TABLE #link (linkid VARCHAR(10), termid VARCHAR(8), reltype VARCHAR(2), refid VARCHAR(8))
CREATE TABLE #categorylink (code VARCHAR(3), termid VARCHAR(8))

INSERT INTO #term VALUES ('100', 'ABC', 'abc_scopenote')
INSERT INTO #term VALUES ('120', 'DEF', 'def_scopenote')
INSERT INTO #term VALUES ('150', 'GHI', NULL)

INSERT INTO #link VALUES ('1', '100', 'NT', '120')
INSERT INTO #link VALUES ('2', '100', 'NT', '150')
INSERT INTO #link VALUES ('3', '120', 'BT', '100')
INSERT INTO #link VALUES ('4', '120', 'RT', '150')
INSERT INTO #link VALUES ('5', '150', 'BT', '100')
INSERT INTO #link VALUES ('6', '150', 'RT', '120')

INSERT INTO #categorylink VALUES ('S01', '100')
INSERT INTO #categorylink VALUES ('S02', '100')
INSERT INTO #categorylink VALUES ('B04', '150')

SELECT
       CASE
       WHEN #term.enscope IS NULL AND refterm.en IS NULL AND #categorylink.code IS NULL
       THEN #term.en
       ELSE NULL
       END,
       CHAR(9) + 'SN ' + #term.enscope,
       CHAR(9) + #link.reltype + CHAR(32) + refterm.en,
       CHAR(9) + 'CODE ' + #categorylink.code
    FROM #link
        INNER JOIN #term ON #term.termid = #link.termid
        INNER JOIN #term AS refterm ON refterm.termid = #link.refid
        LEFT JOIN #categorylink ON #term.termid = #categorylink.termid

    GROUP BY GROUPING SETS (#term.en, (#term.en, #term.enscope), (#term.en, #link.linkid, #link.reltype, refterm.en), (#term.en, #categorylink.code))
    ORDER BY #term.en, #categorylink.code, #link.linkid, #term.enscope
GO

DROP TABLE #term
DROP TABLE #link
DROP TABLE #categorylink
GO
```

If there is NULL in 'enscope' I've got a duplicate row.

If there is no 'categorylink' value I've got a duplicate row.

How to avoid this, please?

I want to COALESCE them all into a single column without duplicates.

```
; WITH CTEterm AS (
    SELECT
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY #term.en, refterm.en ORDER BY #term.en) AS rownumber,
       #term.en AS mainterm,
       CHAR(9) + 'SN ' + #term.enscope AS scopenote,
       CHAR(9) + #link.reltype + CHAR(32) + refterm.en AS subterms,
       CHAR(9) + 'CODE ' + #categorylink.code AS codes
    FROM #link
       INNER JOIN #term ON #term.termid = #link.termid
       INNER JOIN #term AS refterm ON refterm.termid = #link.refid
       LEFT JOIN #categorylink ON #term.termid = #categorylink.termid
)

SELECT COALESCE(
    CASE
    WHEN rownumber = 1
    THEN mainterm
    ELSE NULL
    END,
    scopenote,
    subterms,
    codes
)
FROM CTEterm
GROUP BY GROUPING SETS ((mainterm, rownumber), (mainterm, scopenote), (mainterm, subterms), (mainterm, codes))
ORDER BY mainterm, codes, subterms, scopenote

GO
```

Basically how to avoid using 'ELSE NULL' in CASE (like 'else skip row')?

This is what I get using COALESCE

```
ABC
NULL
    SN abc_scopenote
    NT DEF
    NT GHI
    CODE S01
    CODE S02
NULL
DEF
    SN def_scopenote
    BT ABC
    RT GHI
NULL
GHI
    BT ABC
    RT DEF
    CODE B04
```

This is what I need

```
ABC
    SN abc_scopenote
    NT DEF
    NT GHI
    CODE S01
    CODE S02
DEF
    SN def_scopenote
    BT ABC
    RT GHI
GHI
    BT ABC
    RT DEF
    CODE B04
```

Same question [here](http://www.sqlteam.com/forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=161693)

Comment: What does your expected result set look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry if this turns out not really what you expected, but if you simply need to get rid of NULLs then I fail to see why you can't just do like this:

```
;WITH CTEterm AS (
    SELECT
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY #term.en, refterm.en
                              ORDER BY #term.en) AS rownumber,
       #term.en AS mainterm,
       CHAR(9) + 'SN ' + #term.enscope AS scopenote,
       CHAR(9) + #link.reltype + CHAR(32) + refterm.en AS subterms,
       CHAR(9) + 'CODE ' + #categorylink.code AS codes
    FROM #link
       INNER JOIN #term ON #term.termid = #link.termid
       INNER JOIN #term AS refterm ON refterm.termid = #link.refid
       LEFT JOIN #categorylink ON #term.termid = #categorylink.termid
)
SELECT
  AggValue
FROM (
  SELECT
    mainterm, codes, subterms, scopenote,
    COALESCE(
      CASE WHEN rownumber = 1 THEN mainterm ELSE NULL END,
      scopenote,
      subterms,
      codes
    ) AS AggValue
  FROM CTEterm
  GROUP BY GROUPING SETS ((mainterm, rownumber), (mainterm, scopenote),
                          (mainterm, subterms), (mainterm, codes))
) s
WHERE AggValue IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY mainterm, codes, subterms, scopenote
```

Note: `ELSE NULL` is removed here only because it changes nothing (`NULL` is implied when there's no `ELSE`), not because you would gain anything from removing it.

Comment: By the way, this ROW_NUMBER() expression is enough (PARTITION BY #term.en ORDER BY #term.en) Generates more NULLs behind but runs two times faster.